# Insert one table data into another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, insert

In my database currently, have 2 tables with data called `student` and `subject`.

[image]

In my web application have a new requirement, so I have to add additional mapping table called `StudentSubject`. However now I need to insert data to that table(StudentSubject) as follows. How can I write a script to achieve it? And may I know should I need to write `Pre-Deployment` or `Post-Deployment` Script to do this? If yes how can I do it?

[image]

Comment: This feels like homework. Is this an SQL question, or a C# question? Just to be clear, either way you really should be having a go at doing this yourself and then asking a specific question about whatever you're having trouble with.

Comment: @Ben Sorry sir. Actually, this is my university project. I stack on this. I don't know how to handle this from my ASP web app. which means should I need to run Pre-Deployment or Post-Deployment script? I searched on the internet and withing that time I saw there is some option called Pre-Deployment and Post-Deployment. but I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple by cross Join.

```
INSERT INTO StudentSubject
SELECT StudentId, SubjectId 
FROM Student, Subject

--OR 

INSERT INTO StudentSubject
SELECT StudentId, SubjectId 
FROM Student 
CROSS JOIN Subject
```

Comment: I'm not clear about your answer. Can you please give me a complete answer

Comment: and please be noted, I don't need to select data, I need to insert data to table

Comment: `Cross join` with `Student table` one record with all records of `Subject table`.

Comment: it is good practice to specify the column name explicitly in the `INSERT` statement. Also please use ANSI join syntax `table1 CROSS JOIN table2`

Comment: @Squirrel okay. I will add that one.